# Replace NAs in certain columns

Tags: r

I think I am very close to the solution.
But unfortunately I don't get it.

```
x1kb <- c(1:10, NA, NA, 5,6,7,8)
y1 <- rep(c(NA,777),each=8)
x2kb <- c(1:10, NA, NA, 5,6,7,8)
y2 <- rep(c(NA,777),each=8)
data1<- data.frame(x1kb, y1, x2kb, y2)
```

This is how the dataframe looks like:

```
   x1kb  y1 x2kb  y2
1     1  NA    1  NA
2     2  NA    2  NA
3     3  NA    3  NA
4     4  NA    4  NA
5     5  NA    5  NA
6     6  NA    6  NA
7     7  NA    7  NA
8     8  NA    8  NA
9     9 777    9 777
10   10 777   10 777
11   NA 777   NA 777
12   NA 777   NA 777
13    5 777    5 777
14    6 777    6 777
15    7 777    7 777
16    8 777    8 777
```

I tried it with `dplyr`. But I always get an error.

```
library(dplyr)
#replace NA with 0 if colname includes "kb"
data1[is.na(data1)] <- 0 %>% select(data1, contains("kb"))
```

My desired output:

```
   x1kb  y1 x2kb  y2
1     1  NA    1  NA
2     2  NA    2  NA
3     3  NA    3  NA
4     4  NA    4  NA
5     5  NA    5  NA
6     6  NA    6  NA
7     7  NA    7  NA
8     8  NA    8  NA
9     9 777    9 777
10   10 777   10 777
11    0 777    0 777
12    0 777    0 777
13    5 777    5 777
14    6 777    6 777
15    7 777    7 777
16    8 777    8 777
```

Comment: @akrun: I think it is a different question. Your link only clears half of my question and not the important thing which is to replace NAs only in some columns but not in all.

Comment: Okay,  I reopened it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a dplyr solution with `mutate_each`. You can use the same selectors you use in `select()` to restrict it to the columns you want. Here I use `ends_with`.

```
data1 <- mutate_each(data1, funs=funs(ifelse(is.na(.),0,.)), ends_with("kb"))
```

Edit: recent version of dplyr have soft deprecated `*_each()` functions. Using `across()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64667620/4132844) for an example. Here, the new answer would be:

```
data1 <- mutate(data1, across(ends_with("kb"), ~ifelse(is.na(.x),0,.x)))
```

Comment: Note that if the columns of interest are factors, the factor values will be replaced with their numerical indices

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64667557/how-to-replace-nas-in-multiple-columns-with-dplyr for an answer using updated **dplyr** code.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
data1$x1kb[is.na(data1$x1kb)] <- 0
data1$x2kb[is.na(data1$x2kb)] <- 0
```