# How to replace NAs in multiple columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to replace `NA`s in the columns that begin with `v` with the values in column `x` using current **dplyr** (1.0.2) code.

The same question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150448/replace-nas-in-certain-columns), but the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35150632/5314416) is outdated.

I have no trouble with one column:

```r
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(NA, 1, 2), v2 = c(3, NA, 4), v3 = c(5, 6, NA), x = c(7, 8, 9))
df %>% mutate(v1 = coalesce(v1, x))
#>   v1 v2 v3 x
#> 1  7  3  5 7
#> 2  1 NA  6 8
#> 3  2  4 NA 9
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

but can't figure out how to get it to work across multiple columns.

Here are a few things I've tried to no avail:

```r
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(NA, 1, 2), v2 = c(3, NA, 4), v3 = c(5, 6, NA), x = c(7, 8, 9))
df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("v")), . = coalesce(., x))
#> Error in list2(...): object 'x' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(NA, 1, 2), v2 = c(3, NA, 4), v3 = c(5, 6, NA), x = c(7, 8, 9))
df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("v")), . = coalesce(., df$x))
#> Error: Can't combine `..1` <data.frame> and `..2` <double>.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were very close with `across()`. The approach you want is:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("v"), coalesce, x))
```

Notice that the `coalesce` goes *inside* the `across()`, and that `x` (the second argument to `coalesce()` can be provided as a third argument. Result:

```
  v1 v2 v3 x
1  7  3  5 7
2  1  8  6 8
3  2  4  9 9
```

---

If you prefer something closer to your approach with `coalesce(., x)`, you can also pass that as an anonymous function with a `~`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("v"), ~ coalesce(., x)))
```

In other situations, this can be more flexible (for instance, if `.` is not the first argument to the function).

Comment: Aha! I tried the anonymous function approach but with the `)` in the wrong place--no wonder I could never get `across()` to work. Any thoughts on `.` vs `.x` in the anonymous function?

Comment: @jtr13 I use . when I have only one argument, but it doesn’t make a difference and I don’t have an opinion. (Though .x might make it more immediately obvious that it’s not referring to the object passed into the pipe)